# Increasing value of cell

Tags: google-sheets

I want a button in one cell when clicked to increase the value in another cell by 1 for a tally.

Comment: Seems like a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

Click tools, then script editor.
A blank function should appear called my function.
Paste this code OVER it.

```
function addOne() {

var sheetName = "Sheet1" ;

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
var range = ss.getRange("A1");
var value = range.getValue();

range.setValue(value + 1);



}
```

Change the sheetname "Sheet1" to whatever your sheet is called (if different)
Click save.

next insert the image. 
In the top right is a drop down arrow saying assign script. 
Type in the box "addOne" no quotes.

Then your script should be on your image, and everytime the button is clicked, it will add one to A1